# Height of div when totally expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a div which has a height limit. Now I would like to know how high the div would be if there was no height limit set. 
How can I get that?

Daniel

Comment: `alert($('#IdOfYourElement').css('height'));`

or

`alert(document.getElementById('yourDivId').style.height);`

Comment: Temporarily, remove height limit. then check the height using javascript/jquery. and then keep the height limit again.

Comment: If you use any Web Developer tools with your browser, you should be able to turn on and off any CSS properties of any elements. Just turn off the `max-height` and then check the actual height.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using Jquery then for example your div id is `test` then you can get the height `$('#test').height();`.

Answer (score 0):

Try code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert($("div").height());
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zCVMz/

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to:

- get the element `.height()`
- set the CSS `height` to `auto`
- store that height into a variable
- reset to old height

```
$(function(){

   var $test = $('#test');        // cache element

   var orgH = $test.height();     // get LIMITED height
   $test.css({height:"auto"});    // go to non-limited height
   var couldBeH = $test.height(); // store that one
   $test.css({height: orgH});     // reset org height

   alert("Could be "+ couldBeH);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript:

```
var $div = $('div');
var height = $div.height();
$div.css('height','auto');

var newHeight = $div.height();
$div.css('height',height);

alert('original height:' + height) ;
alert('new height:' + newHeight) ;
```

[SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/az4LZ/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var mydivheight = document.getElementById('myDiv').clientHeight;
var mydivheight  = document.getElementById('myDiv').offsetHeight;
var mydivheight  = document.getElementById('myDiv').scrollHeight;
```

**clientHeight**- *Includes the height and vertical padding.*

**offsetHeight**- *Includes the height, vertical padding, and vertical borders.*

**scrollHeight**- *Includes the height of the contained document (would be greater than just height in case of scrolling), vertical padding, and vertical borders.*